# Centering Image In UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am having a lot of problems centering an image in my `UITableViewCell`. I have spent countless hours trying all the solutions listed on stack overflow as well as countless other websites. My text will center, but for some reason my image won't center and there is a white line on the left side of the table that I can not get rid of either.(From what I have read in the iOS documentation, this is new in iOS 7, but people have gotten it to go away) I have set all the insets to zero both programmatically and via the inspector. I am using core data to retrieve the images, which is working fine, it is just my image won't center.

Here is my method for the tableViewCell

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (!cell) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                  reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

// Configure the cell...
NSManagedObject *moment = [self.moments objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [moment valueForKey:@"name"]];
UIImage *cellImage = [UIImage imageWithData:[moment valueForKey:@"image"]];
cell.imageView.image = cellImage;
cell.textLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];



return cell;
}
```

Along with that, I can't seem to get my label to go above the image, which is a whole other problem. But what I have done to try to fix this is make a custom cell subclass, which didn't work. I am all out of resources and ideas to fix this.

***EDIT ABOUT CUSTOM SUBCLASS***
So I might have the wrong idea of a custom subclass of `UITableViewCell`. But what I did was create a class, with two variables, one for the `UIImageView` and the other for the label, in a class called customCell. Then in the main table view I called them like this:

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (!cell) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                  reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

// Configure the cell...
NSManagedObject *moment = [self.moments objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
//cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [moment valueForKey:@"name"]];
//UIImage *cellImage = [UIImage imageWithData:[moment valueForKey:@"image"]];
//cell.imageView.image = cellImage;
//cell.textLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
//cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
CustomCell *customCell = (CustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
[customCell.cellTitle setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [moment valueForKey:@"name"]]];
[customCell.cellImage setImage:[UIImage imageWithData:[moment valueForKey:@"image"]]];



return cell;
}
```

Then simply in the custom cell class I just connected the label and image to an IBOutlet and synthesized them.

**EDIT 2 CUSTOM SUBCLASS ADDITION**

The header file has two properties. One for cellTitle which is a UILabel and one for cellImage which is a UIImageView.

```
@interface CustomCell : UITableViewCell
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *cellImage;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *cellTitle;
```

The implementation file:

Here I am just synthesizing the two objects.

```
@synthesize cellImage;
@synthesize cellTitle; 

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString       *)reuseIdentifier
{
self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
if (self) {
    // Initialization code
}
return self;
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

// Configure the view for the selected state
}
```

Comment: Why didn't custom UITableViewCell work for you? If you want some custom cell layout, I'd say that's the way for you to go. Try again with the cell subclass and post its code here, I'm sure we will be able to help you.

Comment: You probably do want a custom subclass of UITableViewCell. Then you can set up the cell layout in IB. If you're using auto layout you could set up the constraints to make the image view centered inside the cell content view. Your code is just creating  vanilla cell, and in a default cell the image view is pinned to the left side of the cell, so your code will not work as posted. Post your and info about layout for your attempt at a custom subclass of UITableViewCell.

Comment: @DuncanC I have updated my code up top to show the custom cell.

Comment: @johnyu I have updated my code up top to show the custom cell.

Comment: The edited code is not using your custom cell class. instead of "cell = [[UITableviewCell alloc...", you would need "cell = [[CustomCell alloc..." or whatever your custom cell class is called.

Comment: @DuncanC I changed that, I just get a blank cell. I can delete the cell though. I had content in the cell before the change, so obviously the cell is recognizing content in there, just not displaying it. I changed it too `if (!cell) {
        cell = [[CustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                      reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }` As well as `CustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];`

Comment: Can you show us the code of your CustomCell class as well? Oh and you could probably remove the first version of your code (in the original part of the post) to tidy it up a bit, since you're probably going to use just the version from update (with custom class) anyway.

Comment: @johnyu I think I should leave it to show progression, if someone has the similar problem, it might help out a little. But I just added the subclass. It really does nothing other than creating those two objects. I would think I should put the information for the label and view to display in there, but it wouldn't be in the tableview which might case problems too. I am extremely confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long day of trying to figure this out, I had one little mistake that caused this whole debacle. I had my cell Identifier set to "CellIdentifier" in the inspector. I changed it to "Cell" and edited some code and boom!

I added some code to the CustomCell:

```
-(void)layoutSubviews {
self.imageView.center = self.contentView.center;
[super layoutSubviews];
}
```

Which fixed everything. No more bar on the right side and both title and image are centered. Here is the final code in the TableViewController.m

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
//CustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (!cell) {
    cell = [[CustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                  reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

// Configure the cell...
NSManagedObject *moment = [self.moments objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
/*cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [moment valueForKey:@"name"]];
UIImage *cellImage = [UIImage imageWithData:[moment valueForKey:@"image"]];
cell.imageView.image = cellImage;
cell.textLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];*/
[cell.cellImage setImage:[UIImage imageWithData:[moment valueForKey:@"image"]]];
[cell.cellTitle setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [moment valueForKey:@"name"]]];









return cell;
}
```

I still have commented out code in there, sorry about that. But thank you to all whole helped out in solving this problem!

Answer (score 1):

```
CustomCell *customCell = (CustomCell *)[tableView 
      dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
[customCell.cellTitle setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", 
      [moment valueForKey:@"name"]]];
[customCell.cellImage setImage:
      [UIImage imageWithData:[moment valueForKey:@"image"]]];
return cell;
```

I believe you're returning the default `cell`, not the `customCell`

Comment: Firstly, thank you for your response! When I try your code, I first get a warning stating "Incompatible pointer types assigning to 'Custom Cell *' from 'UITableViewCell *' Then when I run I get a SIG kill error stating -[UITableViewCell cellTitle]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x12ee49ca0

Comment: it's actually your code. all I was saying was that you populated `customCell` with data, yet still returned `cell`. `CustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];` should work anyway, however, I can't quite grasp it.

Answer (score 0):

To your cell subclass make a method

```
- (void)layoutSubviews {
    self.cellTitle.frame = CGRectMake(...); //self.view.frame will return the cell's frame
    self.cellImage.frame = CGRectMake(...); //you should set the frames of title and imageView however you want them in here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- (void)layoutSubviews {
  [Self.cellImage setCentre:Self.contentView.Centre];}

Comment: you can make custom cell for table view and load this cell in table view as you can place your contents in custom cell at desired position whatever you want.This is the best approach to make table view cell if your application requires complex design in table view.

Answer (score 0):

DONT USE THE DEFAULT IMAGEVIEW FROM THE CELL... create a UIImageView... add it to cell's view at the desired position.. =)
GL HF

Answer (score 0):

you can make custom cell for table view and load this cell in table view as you can place your contents in custom cell at desired position whatever you want.This is the best approach to make table view cell if your application requires complex design in table view.Example:static NSString *CustomCellIdentifier = @"CEll";//[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Cell%d",indexPath.row];

```
customCell *cell = (customCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: CustomCellIdentifier]; implement this in your cellforrowAtIndexPath method and add your cell nib -(id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
```

{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self)
    {

```
    self = (customCell *)[[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"customCell" owner:self options:nil] firstObject];}
```

}